# Sqlite how to write sqlite data table column row into excell using python

Tags: python, excel, sqlite, xlsxwriter

Hi I want to insert my sqlite data into excell using python. I know how to import row values but I don't know how to import table column names. I need output like in the first row of excell: table column names, in the second row: column values and etc.

```
import sqlite3
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
workbook = Workbook('Resssult.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

conn=sqlite3.connect('DGA_data.db')
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute("select * from users")
mysel=c.execute("select * from users ")
for i, row in enumerate(mysel):
    for j, value in enumerate(row):
        worksheet.write(i, j, row[j])
workbook.close()
```

output should be smth like this:

```
     A    B
   1 id  name
   2 1   Alex
   3 2   Rubick
   4 3   John
   5 4   Mathew
```

Current output

```
1   1 Alex
2   2 Rubick 
3   3 John
4   4 Mathew
```

Comment: _I know how to import row values but I don't know how to import table column names._ Can you clarify what you mean? _output should be smth like this:_ What is the current output? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Ok I did now you can look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using ***pandas*** library.

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 as sqlite
connection = sqlite.connect('database/path')
pd.read_sql_query('your sql query', connection).to_excel('path/and/name/of/excel/file/to/be/created') # You could also give it an existing ExcelWriter object
```

---

And here is how to do it with only sqlite3:
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3 as sqlite
connection = sqlite.connect('database/path')
data = cursor.execute('select * from users').fetchall()
columns_names = [column_tuple[0] for column_tuple in cursor.description]

Add columns_names to the first row of your spreadsheet, then iterate over the data adding them row by row as you did.

Comment: Is there way I can do solve my problem only with sqlite and xlsxwriter? I don't know how to use pandas yest

Comment: Is there way I can solve my problem only with sqlite and xlsxwriter?

Comment: @TimAlym just updated the answer to use only sqlite3.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/8060951/mohamed-abdultawab Sir I would be very pleased if you could show me how to iterate over the data. I tried to do in my way but I ended up overwriting things. Thank you